# What can I do to save the instance state of a fragment but still provide a landscape layout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, rotation, oncreate

if the question sounds weird at first, here comes the explanation:

I have got an activity that hosts my three fragments. Since I would like one of my fragments to save its instance state when the device is rotated, I defined this in my manifest for my activity that hosts the fragments:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

This works just fine. However, now I have got an other problem: One of my other fragments uses a special landscape layout. The problem is, that this layout is not used immediately on device rotation. I think it is because the new layout only gets set on `onCreate`.

What can I do to solve this problem? I want my landscape layout to be set immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

in onCreateView(); method of your Fragment. I think it should do the trick.

Comment: that's what I thought as well. but it is not doing the trick. For me, thats a mystery...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you down need to add the configChanges parameter to your manifest.

You can override [onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) in your Fragment

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, someIntValue);
}
```

This methode should be called before your fragment gets destroyed.

Now in your **onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)** (or **onCreateView()**) methode:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    someIntValue = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX);            
}
```

This way it shouldn't intervene with any other special fragments.